# Angular Material mat-selection-list throws ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on reload

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a question about mat-selection-list and reactive forms.
The problem is that I create mat-selection list and then after I read from the local storage I update my form. Everything works but I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError because it has obviously been created with default values. Is this expected behavior and how can I fix it if it is :)

you can see stack blitz example here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ul58q4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this error is because you set the form initial value but view can't detect it, so by using `changeDetectorRef` after set the initial value it will be right:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, Injectable ,ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { LocalStorageService } from './local-storage.service';

const FILTER_FORM_STORAGE_KEY = 'filterFormStorageKey';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  typesControl: FormControl;

  types: any[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Type A' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Type B' }
  ];

  constructor(private _storage: LocalStorageService,
  private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
      typesControl: this.typesControl = new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const formStorage = this._storage.get(FILTER_FORM_STORAGE_KEY);
    if (formStorage) {
      this.formGroup.patchValue(formStorage);
    }
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  saveForm() {
    console.log('submitted');
    this._storage.set(FILTER_FORM_STORAGE_KEY, this.formGroup.value);   
  }
}
```

working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pjh2sy).

Comment: It seems that you are not "supposed" to change values in ngAfterViewInit, is that the cause of the error if I understood correctly ?

Comment: This is probably the complete answer https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-expressionchangedafterithasbeencheckederror-error-e3fd9ce7dbb4 but never quite understood it

Comment: @Pac0 Same thing happens i belive

Comment: interesting question and answer, I already faced the issue and didn't bother to ask.

Comment: Well if you do it in onInit same thing happens doesnt it? @fatemefazli

Answer (score 1):

We can't able to view the source code in stackblitz. The issue is you are updating the component object after DOM has been updated. You need to manually trigger the change detection to update DOM as well. use

```
setTimeout(()=>{

}, 0);
```

Comment: Works but its looks like a hack

Comment: You can use too `ngZone.run`.